# Tensorflow2: How to print value of a tensor returned from tf.function when eager execution is disabled?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor, eager-execution

I've read that I can see contents of tf variables by using `tf.print` inside my `tf.function` definition. It doesn't work. My `__tf.version__` is 2.5.0. I run the following function inside Jupyter notebook:

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

@tf.function
def tf_fun(inputs):
    x = tf.strings.lower(inputs)
    tf.print(x)
    return x
```

- without print

```
tf_fun(inputs)
<tf.Tensor 'StatefulPartitionedCall_6:0' shape=(7,) dtype=string>
```

- with print

```
print(tf_fun(inputs))
Tensor("StatefulPartitionedCall_5:0", shape=(7,), dtype=string)
```

I want eager execution to be disabled because I use some functions from `tf.Transform` module that works only in graph mode somewhere else in this notebook.
**How can I see the contents of tensor to make sure that my function produces exactly what I want?**

Another problem (less important) is that if I try to assing returned value to a variable for further processing `tf.print` prints anything only when it's the first call to `tf_fun` (I know it has something to do with tracing, but I don't understand it and would like to know how to fix it.)

**Edit: after adding something from `tf.Transorm` module I got an error.**

```
@tf.function
def transform_product1(inputs, top_k_products):
    product = tf.strings.lower(inputs)
    product = tf.strings.reduce_join(product, -1, separator = ' ')
    product = tft.vocabulary(product, top_k= 4)
    return product

prod = transform_product1(inputs,4)
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session() 
print(sess.run(prod))
```

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'PartitionedCall_7/vocabulary/temporary_analyzer_output_1/Placeholder' with dtype string
     [[{{node vocabulary/temporary_analyzer_output_1/Placeholder}}]]
```

Comment: With disabling eager execution you need to run a session to trigger graph. Like this: `a=tf_fun(inputs)
sess=tf.compat.v1.Session()
print(sess.run(a))`. Without disabling eager-mode and just with @tf.function decorator you can use `tf.print` with no problem.

Comment: @Kaveh Thanks! Unfortunately I have further problems - I described them in edit

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `force_tf_compat_v1=True` to run  the legacy `tf.Transform` and try to print the function's return by calling the function outside `tf.function`.
Or for the part where you are using tf.transform you can wrap it using `tf.Graph` as below.

```
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
  # Define operations and tensors in `g`.
  c = tf.constant(30.0)
```